# Изменение размера input в соответствии с размером в формы flexbox

Tags: css

При уменьшении размера поле input выходит за края формы:

```
.form-container { width: 230px; }
```

Можно ли как-то динамически уменьшить поле `input`, чтобы не не нарушить форматирование, и сохранить выравнивание чтобы оно осталось в форме?

[Рабочий вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqfnmek)

[Проблемный вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqfnmek/1)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку у Вас `input` помещен внутрь тега `label`, то реализация концепции `responsive` относительно исходного макета будет неполноценной.

Можно задать максимальные размеры для каждого `input'a`:

```
input {
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

что позволит сохранить форматирование и динамически реагировать на изменение размеров.

Имейте ввиду что Вам нужно будет настроить размеры `input'ов` селективно, так как их условия не равны.

Что бы получить полный контроль над позиционированием Вы можете разнести `label` и `input` и используйте для их выравнивания [систему CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: С ```input {
  width: 100%;
}``` теряется форматирование. checkbox уезжает, инпуты разной длины